Test code build failure in GitHub Actions
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
class CouponConcurrencyTest {

    @Autowired
    private CouponService couponService;

    @Autowired
    private RedisLockStockFacade redisLockStockFacade;

    @Autowired
    private UserCouponRepository userCouponRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    CouponIssueParam param;

    List<User> users;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        param = new CouponIssueParam(1L);

        users = userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void after() {
        userCouponRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @DisplayName("one_Issue_coupon")
    void one_Issue_coupon() {
        // given
        User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();

        // when
        couponService.issueCoupon(param, user);

        // then
        int count = userCouponRepository.countByCouponId(param.getCouponId());
        AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat(count).isEqualTo(1L);
    }
}

The test code mentioned above typically references an application-test.properties file in the test class setup.
spring.application.name=Issue-Coupon-Service

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_coupon
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

application-test.properties file is written as described above.
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      
      - name: Setup MySQL
        uses: samin/mysql-action@v1
        with:
          mysql version: '8.0.33' 
          mysql root password: '1234' 
          mysql database: 'test_coupon'  
          mysql user: 'root'  
          mysql password: 'dbsehdwn12!' 
          character set server: 'utf8'  
          collation server: 'utf8_unicode_ci'  

      # Execut Gradle
      - name: Run chmod to make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      # Bulid Test
      - name: Build with Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@bd5760595778326ba7f1441bcf7e88b49de61a25 # v2.6.0
        with:
          arguments: build


      - name: Publish Test Results
        uses: EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          files: |
            **/build/test-results/**/*.xml


      - name: Publish Test Report
        uses: mikepenz/action-junit-report@v3
        if: success() || failure() 
        with:
          report_paths: '**/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml'

GitHub Actions is configured as mentioned above.
It seems like everything that needed to be set up has been done.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7048d039 testClass = com.coupon.issuecouponservice.service.coupon.CouponConcurrencyTest, locations = [], classes = [com.coupon.issuecouponservice.IssueCouponServiceApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [PropertySourceDescriptor[locations=[classpath:/application-test.properties], ignoreResourceNotFound=false, name=null, propertySourceFactory=null, encoding=null]], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@4ce7fffa, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6bbe2511, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4dd02341, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6399551e, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@42bb9565], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] [n/a]

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I keep getting the errors mentioned above.
What could be the reason?
I haven't set up a separate test server; the tests run fine just in the local environment.
I can't figure out the cause.
